# Is Continous Integration on TFS using Bitbucket possible?

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a CI build on TFS Online. I'm pretty much used to it using the tfs git repository.
The actual team I'm working with however uses Bitbucket. So I started by setting up a build linked to Bitbucket, which worked flawlessly.

However, activating CI seemed to trigger an error from Bitbucket when I save my settings : "Bitbucket returned the error : 'Forbidden'".

[image]

I found 2 possible solutions :

- Use the generic "git remote repository" with which I struggle a bit and it seems strange that I have to set up different connections just for CI.
- Use a third party app (i.e. Zapier) to trigger the build. But honestly, why should I add a new layer of maintenance ?

Any help or suggestion would be welcome.

Thank you !

Quick follow up on this issue : 
I contacted Microsoft about it and it seems CI does work on Bitbucket repositories if they are public.
Support will escalade and we'll see what's the source of the problem.

Comment: Which account you used to create Bitbucket service endpoint? Does he have the permission to create webhook in related Repository in Bitbucket? Try to create webhook manually with that account and check the result.

Comment: I think you nailed it. I cannot access "Settings" and therefore the webhook part on these repositories. I'll check with the admin and see how it goes.

Comment: That is the reason, feel free to post the result here after checking it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was indeed the reason.

Comment: Great! I post an answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you don’t have the permission to create webhook, using another account that have enough permission instead.

Answer (score 0):

As said by starain-MSFT, I did not have the rights to create a web hook on Bitbucket. Check if you can see the "settings" on the repository. If not, that's the reason. Just make sure you have enough rights.